# regex to encapsule paragraph inside markdown file needed

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I am trying to encapsule a limerick (paragraph with escaped line endings / single line breaks) inside some paragraphs of a markdown file.

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Sed maximus ut dui non malesuada. Duis ultrices erat quis velit rutrum, a elementum lectus dictum.

There was a young lady named Bright\
who traveled much faster than light.\
She set out one day\
in a relative way,\
and came back the previous night.

Nulla in dapibus erat. Integer sed cursus nunc.

Quisque quis neque orci. Aliquam in leo consectetur, molestie massa quis, pretium nulla.
```

Now, how can I achieve this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Sed maximus ut dui non malesuada. Duis ultrices erat quis velit rutrum, a elementum lectus dictum.

<tag>There was a young lady named Bright\
who traveled much faster than light.\
She set out one day\
in a relative way,\
and came back the previous night.</tag>

Nulla in dapibus erat. Integer sed cursus nunc.

Quisque quis neque orci. Aliquam in leo consectetur, molestie massa quis, pretium nulla.
```

I was able to catch the end of the limerick paragraph. But the damn regular expression is too greedy when I use /m and s/ modifiers.

I tried

```
[^\n]^$.+?\\

^$[^\n].+?\\

^$[^\n].+?\\

^$.^.+?\\.+?[^\\]$
```

It really drives me nuts.

Comment: I wonder why you used `^$` at all - it can match an empty string/line. What if the limerick starts at the beginning of the whole string? If you really need to check if the previous line is empty, you may use a negative lookbehind like `(?<!.\r\n|.[\r\n])`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will keep it in mind. But the stuff I am going to analyze is machine generated markdown - so, yes, there should always be an empty line before the limerick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to match *consecutive lines* that *end with `\` except the last line*.

You may use

```
 preg_replace('/^.+\\\\(?:\R.+\\\\)*\R.*/m', '<tag>$0</tag>', $txt)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6r9JhP/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than linebreak symbols as many as possible
- `\\` - a literal `\`
- `(?:\R.+\\)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `\R` - a linebreak
  - `.+` - any 1+ chars other than linebreak symbols
  - `\\`  - a literal `\`
- `\R.*` - a linebreak (`\R`) and any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols (up to the end of line).

Comment: I guess it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer.